# How to return Iframe content from a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, plugins

I want to write a jquery plugin which can submit form using iframe and return the content of iframe as the argument of callback function. But onload event does not return any value. I am a beginner. Can you help?

Comment: the form inside the iframe? ... where is your code? what have you tried?  ... are you asking for a cookbook?

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation

The only situation I can imagine in which you will need to submit a form within an iFrame is if you want to do AJAX uploads, if that's your situation you can take a look at [this plugin](http://lagoscript.org/jquery/upload/download) which implements this very elegantly (and they use an iFrame to submit the file upload)

But if you simply want to submit a form and retrieve the resulting data while staying on the same page, its best not to use an iframe and stick with [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Example:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', form.serializeArray(), function(data) { // Callback function
    $('.result').html(data); // Do what you want with data
}, 'html'); // Retrieve HTML, json etc
```

### If you still need it

If you still need to use an iframe, below is the relevant code from the upload.js plugin:

```
     form.submit(function() { // form would be the form element in the iframe
        iframe.load(function() {
            var data = handleData(this);
                // data will be the resulting content
        });
     }).submit(); // submit form after applying listeners
```

And altering their `handleData()` function:

```
function handleData(iframe) {
            return $(iframe).contents().get(0);
}
```